# Unhandled Exceptions when i target my windows phone 8 app to windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem when I converted my project from windows Phone 8 to windows phone 8.1

I get unhandled exception for a time when i try to show a message :

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.

and after sever runnings RootFrame_NavigationFailed fired.

I didn't change any thing only retargeting and although without retargeting I get the same error if i deployed app to windows phone 8.1.

as there is any change in Windows Phone 8.1 SDK lead to this exception ?

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? which part of your code?

Comment: When i try to show a message box in separated class , before it was working but now it needs Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to work properly